# How to solve $xy'y^2=x^2+y^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'y^2=x^2+y^3$$

In my problems book it is covered as "linear non-homogeneous" equation, but I was not able to bring it to canonical form like

$$y'+yp(x) = q(x)$$

is there any trap about it?

Comment: Hem, $y^2$ or $y^3$ ????

Comment: @YvesDaoust, double checked, $y^3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to know how to solve those in the 'canonical form' you mentioned, I thought it would be useful to provide an answer showing that your ODE can be put into that form. Consider an ODE in the following form:
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
Where $n\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\}$. Such an ODE is called a [Bernoulli Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). In general, such can be reduced to the form you mentioned using the substitution $z=y^{1-n}$. Your ODE can be written in that form:
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y=xy^{-2}$$

---

Hence, in your case, we clearly see that $n=-2$, thus the change of variable $z=y^3$ seems reasonable. Hence $z'=3y^2y'$ by the chain rule and let's now apply this substitution to your original ODE:
$$xy^2y'=x^2+y^3 \implies x\cdot \frac{z'}{3}=x^2+z$$
Which is in the form you mention, after dividing both sides by $\dfrac{x}{3}$ and rearranging:
$$z'-\frac{3}{x}\cdot z=3x$$
And this, you know how to solve.

Comment: Even though this is not the shortest method, I thought it would be worth mentioning that one could reduce the ODE to one of the form
$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$
Which the OP seems to know how to solve. For a short method, I have provided [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499473/how-to-solve-xyy2-x2y3/2499500#2499500).

Comment: does it really work?

I devided both sides with $y^3$ got:

$$xy'\frac{1}{y} = \frac{x^2}{y^3}+ 1$$

then make the substitution $z = \frac{1}{y^2}$ and its derivative: $z' = -\frac{2y'}{y^3}$ and therefore $-\frac{z'}{2} = \{y'}{y^3} $

Comment: Yes, it should work. Why did you divide both sides by $y^3$, and why did you make the substitution $z=\dfrac{1}{y^2}$? I suggested the substitution $z=y^3$, and you can directly apply that to your original ODE.

Comment: well, as far as I remember bernulli's workflow we have to devide both sides of equation with the gratest power of $y$, there the greatest power is $y^3$ and then substitution is by formula $z = y^{1-n}$ and then find $z'$, but I do not give up the idea that I do not know something important, because yesterday I figured that it is better to make $z = \sqrt{y}$ substitution if an original equation has something like $y^{1/2}$

Comment: Indeed, typically one would divide both sides by $y^n$ and then substitute $z=y^{1-n}$, however that only applies if your ODE is in the form:
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
Which your original ODE isn't yet:
$$xy'y^2=x^2+y^3$$
$$y'=\frac{x^2+y^3}{xy^2}$$
$$y'=\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{1}{x}y$$
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y=xy^{-2}$$
Now, it suggests that you should divide your equation by $y^n$ and substitutute $z=y^{1-n}$, but dividing by $y^{-2}$ would be quite useless since your original ODE already contains that $y^2$ term. Hence, it is more logical to just apply the substitution to your original ODE.

Comment: oops, I missed that point and this knocked me down, but how did you figure out that $z = y^3$ should be applied here, any general hints which can be applied for the future equations? (I  am trying to figure out some patterns for the future)

Comment: I figured it out, by realizing that after some manipulation, you could write it in the form of a Bernoulli ODE, as shown above:
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y=xy^{-2}$$
Hence, it was evident that the substitution $z=y^{1-(-2)}=y^3$ would reduce your ODE to a linear non-homogeneous one.

Comment: thanks, I've not known that we have to also make bernulli's equation from given one, I only thought that if you see $y^n$ and $n \ne 1$ you can just apply steps, but that's why these tasks exist

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$y'y^2=\frac{(y^3)'}3.$$

---

Now the homogenous equation is

$$\frac{x(y^3)'}3=(y^3),$$ which is separable.

> The homogenous solution is $y^3=Cx^3$, or $y=Cx$.

You can try the complete solution by variation of the constant.

Comment: Hmm, I've never faced such a approach (yet), how did you get it and when could it be applied?

Comment: @M.Mass: just observation. Now you have $y^3$ on both sides, and as announced the equation is linear.

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly, that $(y^3)'$ is being taken as derivative of implicit function?

Comment: @M.Mass: it's the derivative of the cube of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick, which is perhaps the shortest method, is to use the change of variable $y=vx$, giving $y'=xv'+v$ by the product rule. This gives:
$$\begin{align}xy'y^2=x^2+y^3 &\implies y'=\frac{x^2+y^3}{xy^2}=\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{y}{x}\\&\implies xv'+v=\frac{1}{xv^2}+v \\&\implies v'=\frac{1}{x^2v^2} \end{align}$$
This ODE is [separable](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx), meaning that all you need to do is to compute the following integrals.
$$\int v^2~dv=\int \frac{1}{x^2}~dx$$

Comment: so it works like for homogeneous first ordered equations wehe we do $y = tx$ and then find either $dy$ or $y'$?